# Alternative general formula for the probability of rolling two dice and getting one number on at least one of them.

Tags: probability, statistics, dice

Let's say I want to know what's the probability of rolling two 6-sided dice and getting a 6 in at least one of them.

The probability of not getting a 6 in one die is 3/6. I know I can use the following formula for that:

> Probability of not getting a 6: (5/6)^2 -> 25/36
>
> - Formula: (probability of not getting a 6)^(number of tries)
>
> Probability of getting a 6: 1-(5/6)^2 -> 11/36
>
> - Formula: 1-(probability of not getting a 6)^(number of tries)
>   All good until this point.

This made me think: To calculate the probability of "getting a 6 in at least one die", I need to use the probability of "not getting a 6 in at least one die" and subtract that from the "total probability".

Which leads to my question: **Is there a general formula that lets me calculate the probability of "getting a 6 in at least one die" that doesn't rely on the subtracting the opposite probability from one?**

P.S.: I'm not asking whether there's a "better" formula, just wondering if there's a different general way of calculating it (even if it's more complicated or longer).

Comment: Sure, you just have to sum over the cases.  To get at least one means you got exactly $1, 2, \cdots, n$ (assuming there are exactly $n$ trials. ).  Easy to do each case and sum.  the "reverse" method is better because you avoid the sum.

Comment: This is a binomial distribution: the probability of exactly $1$ six is ${2\choose 1}\left(\frac16\right)^1\left(\frac56\right)^1 = \frac{10}{36}$ while the probability of exactly $2$ sixes is ${2\choose 2}\left(\frac16\right)^2\left(\frac56\right)^0 = \frac{1}{36}$, so the probability of at least $1$ six is $\frac{11}{36}$

Comment: per the binomial theorem: $1 = \underbrace{\binom{n}{0}p^0(1-p)^n}_{0\text{ success}} + \overbrace{\underbrace{\binom{n}{1}p^1(1-p)^{n-1}}_{1\text{ success}}+\underbrace{\binom{n}{2}p^2(1-p)^{n-2}}_{2\text{ success}}+\dots+\underbrace{\binom{n}{n}p^n(1-p)^0}_{n\text{ success}}}^{\geq 1\text{ success}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p_0$ be the probability of getting a 6 in each individual throw, let $n$ be the number of dice throws you carry out.

To calculate the probability of getting atleast one 6, you would need to sum the probabilities of getting exactly $i$ 6's, where $i$ ranges from 1 to $n$.

$$P\text{(atleast one six)=}\sum_{i=1}^n P(\text{exactly }i \text{ sixes)}$$

To find $P(\text{exactly }i \text{ sixes)}$, you would need to get a six in any $i$ trials out of the $n$ trials, and one of the other five numbers in the rest of the ($n-i$) trials. Keep in mind that the sixes can be in any order, so there are a total of $n\choose i$ possible combinations.
$$\implies  P(\text{exactly }i \text{ sixes)}= (p_0)^i \cdot(1-p_0)^{n-i}\cdot {n\choose i} $$

$$\implies P\text{(atleast one six)=}\sum_{i=1}^n \left[(p_0)^i \cdot(1-p_0)^{n-i}\cdot {n\choose i} \right]  $$

At this point, you could get your answer by calculating this sum manually, but a little manipulation can make this expression much simpler. Notice that $$\sum_{i=0}^n \left[(p_0)^i \cdot(1-p_0)^{n-i}\cdot {n\choose i} \right]=(1-p_0)^n+\sum_{i=1}^n \left[(p_0)^i \cdot(1-p_0)^{n-i}\cdot {n\choose i} \right]$$

By the binomial theorem, the left hand side is simply equal to $(p_o+1-p_0)^n=1 $ $$\implies \sum_{i=1}^n \left[(p_0)^i \cdot(1-p_0)^{n-i}\cdot {n\choose i} \right] =1-(1-p_0)^n$$

Recall that $(1-p_0)$ is simply the probability of not getting a six in a single trial, and thus $(1-p_0)^n$ is the probability of not getting a six in $n$ trials. So you end up with the same simplified expression.

Comment: I assume the result of a combination `(n i)` where `n = i` is 1, right?

In any case, most enlightening. It's been a while since I've done some statistics, but this made total sense. Thanks!

Comment: @Strinnityk yes. There is only one way of choosing i objects from n distinct objects when I=n